# Delete Rows based on multiple cell values in a column under a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm still new to VBA. This is a new post created as I was not specific enough in the previous one.
My Objective: I would like to delete my data row based on a column of data from another sheet.

I have a sheet of data name: `WorkingData`.
`WorkingData` is a list of database with `ProductIDs` which is under Column A 
The `productIDs` would exist more than once because it is identified by period.

```
ProductIDs    Date
132           30/9/2018
132           30/8/2018
132           30/7/2018
122           30/9/2018
122           30/8/2018
11            30/7/2018
11            30/6/2018
...
```

Sheets(ID to Exclude)

```
ProductID
11
23
55
34
.....
```

I have a external sheet name: `IDs to exclude`.
In the `Sheets("IDs to exclude")` under column A, there is a list of IDs to exclude because they are unclean data. However, every month the list **will keep adding up** so the range has to identify the last row.

This is my code but I can only do it row by row. There are thousands of data entry. please advise thanks!

```
Sub delete_Ids()
    Dim c As Range, MyVals As Range, SrchRng As Range
    Dim i As Long, lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, x

    'This is a range containing all the criteria to search for
    lr1 = Sheets("WorkingData").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set MyVals = Sheets("ProductIDs to Exclude").Range("A2:A" & lr1)

    Set SrchRng = Selection
    lr2 = SrchRng.Rows.Count

    For i = lr2 To 1 Step -1
        For Each c In MyVals
    x = InStr(SrchRng(i), c)

    If x > 0 Then
                SrchRng(i).EntireRow.Delete
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    Next i  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code faster:

1. Read data (column A) into an array `ArrIDs`
2. Read IDs to excude into an array `ArrExclude`
3. Loop throug the data `ArrIDs` and
4. Check if it matches any of the IDs to exclude using the WorksheetFunction.Match method.
5. Collect all rows that match into a variable `RowsToDelete`
6. Delete them at once in the end.

This would be one of the fastest ways I think.

The issue is that every read/write action to a cell takes much time, so we try to reduce them. If you delete each row on its own then you have **a lot of** write actions. But if you collect them first using Union and delete them at once you only have **one** write action.

The same applies to reading the cell values. If we reduce it to **one** read action into the array instead of **multiple** read actions each time we need to compare a value then this would be much faster.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AlternativeDeleteIDs()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet 'define datat sheet
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WorkingData")

    Dim ArrIDs() As Variant 'read data into array
    ArrIDs = wsData.Range("A1", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value

    Dim ArrExclude() As Variant 'read IDs to exclude into array
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IDs to exclude")
        ArrExclude = .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value
    End With

    Dim RowsToDelete As Range 'we collect all rows to delete here
    Dim MatchedRow As Long

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(ArrIDs, 1) + 1 To UBound(ArrIDs, 1) '+1 because of header in data
        MatchedRow = 0 'initialize
        On Error Resume Next 'next line throws error if ID is not in exclude list
        MatchedRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ArrIDs(iRow, 1), ArrExclude, False)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If MatchedRow <> 0 Then 'ID was found in exclude list
            'mark ID for delete
            If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set RowsToDelete = wsData.Rows(iRow)
            Else
                Set RowsToDelete = Union(RowsToDelete, wsData.Rows(iRow))
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

    'delete all rows at once
    RowsToDelete.Delete
End Sub
```

So in this code we only have 2 read actions (into array) and 1 write action (delete).

Comment: Works like a charm!! Thanks very much!